# Calculating area of triangle using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to calculate the area of a triangle using JavaScript, HTML and styling the page using CSS.

I'm having a little trouble with the CSS, and I really don't know where to start on the JS. Not looking for a solution but just a good place to start and maybe some links would be much appreciated. Here's what I know i'll need to do:

1. Verify width and height are numbers and are greater than 0 (I have some idea how to do this using if statements correct?)
2. Verify width is not more than 2x the height and height is not more than 2x the width. I know I need another if statement but have no idea how to structure that.
3. Using my calculate my area, use an onclick event, do the math using JS and change the text box to the result. I know I'll need to declare an object, and then set that result of the object to the value of the text box.

Also for the CSS, you'll see in my current result the text and image is not centered in the way I am aiming for. I centered the block of text, but the text itself is not centered (I tried using text-align: center but that doesn't seem to be working).

Lastly, the image when I do "view image" on Firefox to see why it's not working says "cannot be displayed because it contains errors" yet the image displays just fine on Windows.

Here is my code (again, no JS because not sure where to start):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<title>HTML5 template</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homework14.css">

</head>



<body>
<header>Homework 14</header>

<div id="table1">

<div id="table2">

<div id="table3">

<div id="triangle">
<img src="triangle.gif">
</div>

<div id="table4">

<form>
  <label for="width">Width (b):</label>
  <input type="text" id="width" name="width">
  <label for="height">Height (h):</label>
  <input type="text" id="height" name="height">
</form>
Enter the width and height of your triangle to calculate the area


<input type="button" value="Calculate area">
</div>


</div>

<hr>

<div id="table5">

<form>
  <label for="area">The area is:</label>
  <input type="text" id="area" name="area">
</form>

</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
#table1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    border: solid red;
}

#table2 {
    border: solid blue;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    width: 450px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#table3 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

#table4 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

#table5 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 300px;
}

#triangle {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

hr {
    color: blue;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 5px;
}
```

I know there's a lot here to be answered so really any help is appreciated, especially on the JavaScript, thank you!!

Comment: what do you expect from us?

Comment: Can you make this a [MCVE]?  And are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at jQuery documentation. Great for beginners who are just starting to manipulate the DOM. However, if you are serious about web application development I suggest you use a framework/library like Angular 2, VueJS, or React. Here would be some sample javascript that is using jquery.

```
// put this at very bottom of your html right before </body>
<script>
// using jquery we can get the values inside the input boxes 
var height = $("#height").val();
var width = $("#width").val();
var error = false;
if(height <= 0) {
    error = true;
}
if(width <= 0) {
    error = true;
}
if(width > 2 * height) {
     error = true;
}
if(height > 2 * width) {
    error = true;
}

if(!error) {
    var area = .5 * height * width;
     $("#area").val(area);
}
</script>
```

I dont know what wrong with the images, maybe save that for another SO question.

Comment: @victor Also, $("#height") and $("#width") are inputs, and do not have an `innerText` property, and so `.text()` will not return anything. You should use `.val()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery to get your input values and compute them with a function call from the button click. Here is a working demo:

```js
function calcFunction() {
var base = $("#width").val();
var height = $("#height").val();
if (base > 0 && height > 0 && base <= 2 * height && height <= 2 * base) {
    var solving_triangle = base * height / 2;
    $("#total").val(solving_triangle);
  } else {
    $("#total").val("Out of range");
}}
```

```css
#table1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  border: solid red;
}

#table2 {
  border: solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#table3 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#table4 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#table5 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 300px;
}

#triangle {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#total {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>Homework 14</header>

  <div id="table1">

    <div id="table2">

      <div id="table3">

        <div id="triangle">
          <img src="triangle.gif">
        </div>

        <div id="table4">

          <form>
            <label for="width">Width (b):</label>
            <input type="text" id="width" name="width">
            <label for="height">Height (h):</label>
            <input type="text" id="height" name="height">
          </form>
          <p>Enter the width and height of your triangle to calculate the area</p>


          <button id="calcuate" onclick="calcFunction()">Calculate area
          </button>
          <label for="total">The area of the triangle is:</label>
          <input type="text" id="total"/>
```